# Android can't open file for reading in Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, image-upload

I found this error in logcat, here is the code I take from website:

1. Main.java

   ```
   public class Main extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button upload_btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.upload);
       upload_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               // To open up a gallery browser
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.setType("image/*");
                 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);

           }
       });

   }



   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           if (requestCode == 1) {
           // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
               Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
               System.out.println("Current image Path is ----->" + getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
               TextView tv_path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
               tv_path.setText(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
               HttpUploader uploader = new HttpUploader();
               try {
                 String image_name = uploader.execute(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI)).get();        
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
       }

   }



   //Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
       String [] proj={MediaColumns.DATA};
       android.database.Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
       proj,     // Which columns to return
       null,     // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
       null,     // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
       null);     // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }
   ```

   }
2. HttpUploader.java

   ```
         package com.guerrilla.ptf.view;//set the correct pacage name

   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
   ```

   import com.guerrilla.ptf.view.Base64;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.util.Log;

   ```
   //Uploader class
   public class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String outPut = null;

               for (String sdPath : path) {

                   Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
                   ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                   //Resize the image
                   double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
                   double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
                   double ratio = 400/width;
                   int newheight = (int)(ratio*height);

                   System.out.println("———-width" + width);
                   System.out.println("———-height" + height);

                   bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, 400, newheight, true);

                   //Here you can define .PNG as well
                   bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bao);
                   byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                   String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                   System.out.println("uploading image now ——–" + ba1);

                   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));



                   try {
                       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/api.upload.php");
                       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();                

                       // print response
                       outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                       Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

                       //is = entity.getContent();
                       Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");

                       bitmapOrg.recycle();

                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                   }
               }
               return outPut;
       }
   ```

   }

This was the logcat errors:

```
Applicaton: com.guerrilla.ptf.view
Text: Can't open file for reading
```

Any idea how to solve this errors?

Comment: which line you getting error?

Comment: this is the overriden method  protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)  so move all your code from doInBackground1 to doInBackground(String... arg0)

Comment: sunil: there are no error but just have error in logcat as shown.

Comment: Raghunandan: I move the code in method protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) but the error in logcat still din't slove.
(I edit the coding in above.)

Comment: @Raghunandan, there error still there.. any idea?

Comment: @user2301281 does you url work if i try and post an image. I am testing.

Comment: i send a pic to the url if the url is working let me know if the image is posted to the server. I will post the working code. Not a lot of change. your code is fine. little fine tuning that's all

Answer (score -1):

I saw similar error when I was trying to load 2 fragments in a relative layout. I changed the layout to Linear and problem was resolved!